# Define functions and invoce in window.onload

Tags: javascript

So I have this code:

```
window.onload = function(){
    function myFunction(a, b) {
        return a * b;
    }
}
```

After the page loads, I want to invoce `myFunction()` but it isn't defined and I can't understand why. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to declare your functions inside the `onload` handler. So you can do this:

This puts your `myFunction` function into the global scope and makes it available when you need it.

```js
function myFunction(a, b) {
  return a * b;
}

window.onload = function() {
  let result = myFunction(2, 1);
  console.log(result);
}
```